# extract mail object from json string

Tags: scala, playframework, lift-json

I am have sxtracted json resonse from Yahoo mail webservice. After that i parsed using play json library.

Now i am not not able to iterate over it and construct list of mail objects with sender name, subject, ccList etc.

Mail object i am trying to construct is : List(EmailMessage(subject, recvdDate,body1,sender,recipientsList))

I went through the documentation at [play website](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaJson). But had difficulty in understanding them as a learner in scala. Can someone help me how can we achieve this using case classes.

Response i got form web service :

```
{
    "result": {
        "folder": {
            "folderInfo": {
                "fid": "Sent",
                "name": "Sent"
            },
            "total": 3,
            "unread": 0,
            "size": 943522,
            "isSystem": true
        },
        "total": 3,
        "code": [],
        "message": [
            {
                "mid": "2_0_0_2_3196_ACfai2IAACqmUwNFtgAAAKAUN2U",
                "receivedDate": 1392723382,
                "subject": "test mail",
                "xapparentlyto": "",
                "hasBlockedImages": false,
                "flags": {
                    "isReplied": 0,
                    "isFlagged": 0,
                    "isRead": 1,
                    "isDraft": 0,
                    "isForwarded": 0,
                    "isHam": 0,
                    "isSpam": 0,
                    "hasAttachment": 0,
                    "isRecent": 1,
                    "inAddressBook": 0
                },
                "from": {
                    "email": "rajeevkumar.kallempudi@yahoo.com",
                    "name": "Rajeev Kumar Kallempudi"
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "email": "rajeevprasanna@gmail.com",
                        "name": "rajeevprasanna@gmail.com"
                    }
                ],
                "replyto": [
                    {
                        "email": "rajeevkumar.kallempudi@yahoo.com",
                        "name": "Rajeev Kumar Kallempudi"
                    }
                ],
                "cc": [],
                "bcc": [],
                "domainkey": false,
                "messageId": "<1392723382.76715.YahooMailNeo@web160105.mail.bf1.yahoo.com>",
                "inReplyTo": "",
                "references": "",
                "sender": "rajeevkumar.kallempudi@yahoo.com",
                "part": [
                    {
                        "partId": "HEADER",
                        "type": "x-unknown",
                        "subtype": "",
                        "typeParams": "",
                        "disposition": "",
                        "dispParams": "",
                        "encoding": "7bit",
                        "filename": "",
                        "size": 1474,
                        "contentId": "",
                        "isTruncated": false,
                        "hasBlockedImages": false,
                        "referencedInline": false
                    }                     
                ]
            },
            {
                "mid": "2_0_0_2_2463_ACfai2IAAAdpUwM1NwAAAD0sJOA",
                "receivedDate": 1392719159,
                "subject": "passage1",
                "xapparentlyto": "",
                "hasBlockedImages": false,
                "flags": {
                    "isReplied": 0,
                    "isFlagged": 0,
                    "isRead": 1,
                    "isDraft": 0,
                    "isForwarded": 0,
                    "isHam": 0,
                    "isSpam": 0,
                    "hasAttachment": 0,
                    "isRecent": 1,
                    "inAddressBook": 0
                },
                "from": {
                    "email": "rajeevkumar.kallempudi@yahoo.com",
                    "name": "Rajeev Kumar Kallempudi"
                },
                "to": [
                    {
                        "email": "rajeevkumar.kellmpudi@yahoo.com",
                        "name": ""
                    }
                ],
                "replyto": [
                    {
                        "email": "rajeevkumar.kallempudi@yahoo.com",
                        "name": "Rajeev Kumar Kallempudi"
                    }
                ],
                "cc": [],
                "bcc": [],
                "domainkey": false,
                "messageId": "<1392719159.63976.YahooMailNeo@web160106.mail.bf1.yahoo.com>",
                "inReplyTo": "",
                "references": "",
                "sender": "rajeevkumar.kallempudi@yahoo.com",
                "part": [
                    {
                        "partId": "HEADER",
                        "type": "x-unknown",
                        "subtype": "",
                        "typeParams": "",
                        "disposition": "",
                        "dispParams": "",
                        "encoding": "7bit",
                        "filename": "",
                        "size": 1949,
                        "contentId": "",
                        "isTruncated": false,
                        "hasBlockedImages": false,
                        "referencedInline": false
                    },
                    {
                        "partId": "TEXT",
                        "subtype": "alternative",
                        "type": "multipart",
                        "typeParams": "boundary=\"-827237569-990831377-1392719159=:63976\"",
                        "disposition": "",
                        "dispParams": "",
                        "encoding": "7bit",
                        "filename": "",
                        "size": 11623,
                        "contentId": "",
                        "isTruncated": false,
                        "hasBlockedImages": false,
                        "referencedInline": false
                    }                     
                ]
            } 
        ]
    },
    "error": null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just query Yahoo's messages you won't get the content of emails, so you should use a query that looks more like this.  Please note that this will query all of an account's messages, including read or archived ones.

```
select
  message.subject,
  message.receivedDate,
  message.from,
  message.to,
  message.cc,
  message.bcc,
  message.part.text
from ymail.msgcontent
where (fid,mids) in (
  select
    folder.folderInfo.fid,
    mid
  from ymail.messages
)
```

Once you have that you just need to use the JSON pick element features described in Play's documentation.  It should look something like this:

```
import java.util._

case class EmailMessage(
  subject      : String,
  receivedDate : Date,
  body         : String,
  sender       : String,
  recipients   : List[String]
)

def yahooToEmailMessage(json:JsValue) = {

  val subject = json / "result" / "message" / "subject"
  val body = json / "result" / "message" / "part" / "text"
  val ts = (json / "result" / "message" / "receivedDate").toLong

  val receivedDate = new Date(ts * 1000L)

  val sender = getRecipient(json / "result" / "message" / "to")
  val to  = getRecipients(json / "result" / "message" / "to")
  val cc  = getRecipients(json / "result" / "message" / "cc")
  val bcc = getRecipients(json / "result" / "message" / "bcc")

  val recipients = to ::: cc ::: bcc

  EmailMessage(
    subject,
    receivedDate,
    body,
    sender,
    recipients
  )
}

def getRecipient(recipient:JsValue):List[String] = {

  val name  = recipient / "name"
  val email = recipient / "email"

  name + " <" + email + ">"
}

def getRecipients(array:JsArray):List[String] = {
  array.foldLeft(List[String]()) {
    (list,recipient) => list ::: List(getRecipient(recipient))
  }
}
```

Comment: Jason, 
do u have any idea about this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935025/effective-way-to-process-yahoo-mails-using-yql